# Integrate a chain function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to calculate $\int\operatorname{arccot}(\cot(x))\ dx.$ If I had to find the derivative it would be easy with the chain rule. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Do you mean $$\int arccot(\cot(x))dx$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner exactly

Comment: @Staki42 well I don't even know how to start

Comment: Sorry, isn't $\text {arccot} (\cot (x))$ just $x$?  If you meant some multi-branched thing, then what do you mean by its integral?

Comment: @lulu it's exactly as Dr. Sonnhard wrote it in his comment

Comment: Once again, what do you mean by $\text {arccot} \cot (x)$ if not just $x$?

Comment: @lulu I don't know what u mean by "multi-branched thing". I just have to integrate it

Comment: Ok...let's try this:  what number is $\text {arccot} \cot (0)$?

Comment: @lulu if u meant arccotg(cot(0)) they would cancel out

Comment: Yes, so what would the value be?

Comment: @lulu cot(0) I guess

Comment: You guess?  What is the definition of $\text {arccot}$?  If you have no idea what function you are integrating, then of course you will run into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: integrating by parts we get
$$\int arccot(\cot(x))dx=x arccot(\cot(x))-\int xdx$$
Second hint: $$(arccot(cot(x))'=-\frac{-1-\cot(x)^2}{1+\cot(x)^2}=1$$

Comment: I'm not sure how can I do integration by parts when inside the d I have x... I mean if it was arccot(cotg(x)d(cotgx) ok but I don't get it ...

Comment: And now, can you finish?

Comment: not exactly sure what u did in the second hint

Comment: hm, then try to calculate the derivative of $$arccot(\cot(x))$$

Comment: that is easy then what?

Comment: Then follow my hint and integrate

Comment: ok but I don't really get it how I can use this formula at the moment when under the differential I have only x

Comment: You must integrate by parts, this have i used

Comment: $$(fg)'=f'g+fg'$$

Comment: but I thought you can do by parts integration only if you have multiplication

Comment: Yes this is true, write $$\int 1\cdot arccot(\cot(x))dx$$ and set $$1=f'$$ and $$arccot(\cot(x))=g$$

Comment: @oh I get it now

Comment: Nice, i wish you a nice evening!

Comment: but I don't get where does the extra x in xarccot(cot(x)) come from

Comment: this is $$\int 1dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Let arccot$(\cot x)=y$

$\implies \cot x=\cot y$

$x=n\pi+y$ where $n$ is an integer

$\int y\ dx=?$